# CSS and html: adding margins result in elements not being in a row

Tags: html, css

I have some html code that has some elements in rows:

```
<div class = "row">
<div class="col-sm-3 cont-box">
<h1>Title1<h1>
</div>
<div class="col-sm9 cont-box">  
<img src="onepic.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="dum1">
</div>
</div>
```

When I add margins to the class `cont-box`my browser displays the two elements underneath each other, a line break is added. I would like them to be next to each other, what am I missing?

I am completely new to CSS and html, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: set it to col-sm-2 and col-sm-8 and then give margin on `cont-box`. Seems like you are giving more margin which is getting over to col-sm-12 thats why its going to another line

Comment: Thank you. But this did not do the trick.

Comment: Then it may be some other CSS which is giving line break. Use any addon like Firebug and check

Comment: Hello noobcode. Thank you, I tried again and it solved the issue. But now my row does not span the full width because I have col-sm-5 and col-sm-5 with small margins. How can i make go over the full width? Thank you so much for the solution so far.

Comment: Set some more margin to have it more.

Comment: Any other solution than increasing the margin? I do not want to be that large.

Comment: your question using margin so i did give. Can't give much without checking more code. Better will be to create a fiddle

Comment: True that. I might set up a fiddle it is just that this is work related so I would need to change some things. Thank you so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a margin to bootstrap grid that time when its width reaches above the 12 column grid that time it automatically pushes to down.

To do this add `div` inside the `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9` and add margin to it.

```
 <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="cont-box">
      <h1>Title1<h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">  
     <div class="cont-box">
      <img src="onepic.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="dum1">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add div having class `cont-box`. Sorry I am new to this .

Comment: Just updated the answer please check and let me know if you have any doubt @rashid

Comment: Hello, thank you I now understand. I will check and see what happens.